# What is the difference in launching the shortcut in configure software phase and installation phase in App-V?

Tags: appv

In App-V 4.6 or 5.0 or 5.1, when we are sequencing an application.
First phase is to install our application during sequencing and during this time we can launch the shortcuts also and all these changes will be recorded.

But they have given a separate option for us to launch shortcuts.
Below is the first phase which is during installation capture.
[image]

Below is the 2nd phase specifically for shortcut launch.
To do  these configurations in the “Configure Software” phase, after checking the “I am finished installing” box and clicking “next” in the Sequencer.
[image]

Can anyone please explain what is the difference in launching the shortcut in the above two phases.

Answer (score 0):

The first one records your install while the second one is what it will look like in the virtual environment. So for second one, nothing will be recorded, it will just be something you can kind of see after it's deployed in the client.

Answer (score 0):

The seconds screen is created to make it "dummy proof" so new users know that they can configure installed applications.

The changes you make during the installation phase and in the *configuration software* phase are both recorded. The text in the window says it.

The only difference is that in the *configuration software* phase only the recognized software is visible and may not contain all the apps that you want to configure. Best is to do it during the installation phase.